# Jenkins on OSX gets a identity crisis

Tags: macos, jenkins, uid

I have Jenkins running on OSX 10.8.2. I will often leave a session logged in and su'd into the Jenkins account.

On occasion I will get a cryptic call/email/text from a socially inept user who say simply that "Jenkins is broken" and attaches a useless log snippet indicating that Jenkins could not talk to a remote host because the keys were invalid.  The Jenkins build fails. The first thing I do is a "whoami" on the session I'm logged into.

```
whoami -> _assetcache
I type "exit" 
whoami -> root
sudo su - jenkins
whoami -> jenkins
```

What causes it to think the user has become _assetcache? Why is it fixed by simply logging back into the account? When I check ownership on the jenkins user files they show _assetserver for the user and group too, but logging out and back in seems to clear the issue every time.  Any idea what may be causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: please format you code snippets; refer to the help section in the edit diaplog :)

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to know what causes this, but I have a hack that addresses the issue and for whatever reason, as strange as it may seem, it works:

As root I run a cron script once a hour that executes:  sudo su - jenkins

I don't consider the problem solved, but at least that's a workaround.  Longer term, I'm recommending that we simply move off the OSX platform and onto a AWS platform.